# For-loop exits when adding "offset().left"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

I have a `for-loop` that `appends` a `div` to an element. In the `for-loop`, I want to pass `offset().left` to a variable. Whenever I do that, the `for-loop` exits. If I remove `.left`, it works fine.

How can I add `.offset().top;` in the loop without it exiting?

#### JSFiddle

```js
var vals = 5;

for (var i = 0; i <= vals; i++) {
  var el = $('<div>' + i + '</div>');
  $('#hello').append(el);
  var nothing = $('#nothing').offset().left; // If you comment out ".left" it works fine
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: yellowGreen;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hello"></div>
```

Comment: Have you checked your browser’s error console …?

Comment: Could it be because `#nothing` doesn't exist?!?  If you open up the console you can clearly see it says "Cannot read property 'left' of undefined".  First check to see if `$('#nothing').offset()` is defined before trying to get the `.left` property and always check your console for errors.

Comment: That's it! I forgot to check the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, the reason your loop exited early is because you hit a runtime error, namely:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined"

This is likely because the element with id=nothing does not exist on the page. `$(asdf).offset()` will return `null` if there is no DOM element captured by your selector.

Comment: Correct with the exception of the what `offset()` returns.  It actually returns `undefined` if the node could not be found by jQuery.  To test against an undefined value, you can use `if(typeof myVariable === 'undefined')` or `if(myVariable === undefined)`